# Decode Execution Trace

Tags: embedded, reverse-engineering, stack-trace

I'm doing some firmware analysis for an embedded system and I've got a trace of the program counter (for every cycle, I know what the program counter is set to).  I've additionally got the elf, map file, and the source code.

I'm wondering if there are any open source tools that would allow me to convert this program counter trace into something like a stack trace.  From the map file I can determine which function is executing at any given time, but this doesn't allow me to determine if/where function calls/returns occur.